# How can I remove the state (Bundesland) field completely in a German shop?

Tags: address

When using Market Ready Germany there was such an option. But we use German Setup.

Is there a clean and easy solution to remove this field fully from the system?

Comment: I don't think there is such solution besides a module or editing address format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Magento CE 1.7 you should go into System->Configuration->General->State Options; unselect Germany from countries list and set Display not required State to "No"

If your version is older than 1.7 you need to use an extension, I used this one [Remove/Disable or Change Displayed States and Regions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/12349/s/remove-or-change-displayed-states-and-regions-1964/)